# Unable to deploy API bundle on Apigee using Maven

Tags: maven, apigee

I am unable deploy an API to Apigee using Maven. Following is the command i am using to deploy the bundle to my org on Apigee-

```
mvn clean install -Dusername=xyz@rediffmail.com -Dpassword=PassWord@123 -Dorg=orgName -Ptest
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.211 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-01T17:57:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/179M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (install-bundle-step) on project XYZ-API: MojoExecutionException: connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I notice that build(zip file) is created properly inside target folder, but it's not getting deployed on apigee.

Also i would mention that i am using the setup behind my corporate proxy, and i have accordingly configured the `setting.xml` inside `conf`folder for maven.

What could be the various reasons for this? 
Also please suggest the work around. Thanks in advance

This is detailed error log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (install-bundle-step) on project AllergyIntolerance-FHIR-API: MojoExecutionException: connect timed out -> [Help
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:apigee-edge-maven-plugin:1.0.0:deploy (install-bundle-step) on project AllergyIntolerance-FHIR-API:
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.processHelpfulErrorMessage(DeployMojo.java:343)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1091)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:895)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.rest.RestUtil.uploadBundle(RestUtil.java:342)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.doImport(DeployMojo.java:152)
        at io.apigee.buildTools.enterprise4g.mavenplugin.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:297)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Can you re-run with the `-X` flag on maven and post the log for review?

Comment: Have updated with the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

is emitted when the system is trying to connect to a server, but cannot.  The reason is usually one of two items:

1. The server is not properly named in the profile configuration `<apigee.hosturl>https://api.enterprise.apigee.com</apigee.hosturl>`
2. Your host does not have the ability to reach the server, probably because of a network configuration.  In this case, you may need to configure an outbound proxy.

If you have additional questions you might try http://community.apigee.com for more help.